# Is that possible to create equilibrium arrows using cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

We need equilibrium arrows in the project, so I am curious is it possible to create them using cytoscape.js (maybe some plugin)? If not, are there are any other libraries that can draw bidirectional graph with arrows like these?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.